# How to click a button before running tests with testcafe

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I want to test the pages of my website application. However, I have a disclaimer page that needs to be accepted before you can access the actual application. Is there a way to execute a task (click the accept button in my case) before doing the tests.

Currently, all my tasks fail because they can't pass the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in a [BeforeEach](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-hooks) Step

Answer (score 1):

The code will look something like this:

```
fixture`testing BeforeEach functionality`
  .meta('fixtureID', 'fix-0001')
  .meta({ author: 'luka98v', creationDate: Date() })
  .page`${url}`
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    const acceptButton = Selector('#accept-disclaimer')
    await t
      .click(acceptButton)
  })
```

It works fine.